# Difficulty sending simple telnet commands over Java

Tags: java, command, telnet

I have a process running that listens to a port and I want to send a couple of commands to that process and display its response using the below method. The method can be called multiple times, so I'd like to have short 'telnet sessions' as it were.

```
public String doAction(Message msg) {
    try {
        Socket sock = new Socket(TELNET_IP, TELNET_PORT);

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

        out.println("ping bbbb::1");
        String res = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(res);

        out.close();
        in.close();
        sock.close();

        return res;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
};
```

The parameter msg will contain a couple of strings (such as "ping bbbb::1")but isn't used at the moment. There are a couple of problems with the above method.
When it is first called, it will print the default telnet message "Type "close" to exit" instead of the result of a ping (which, when done manually using telnet using commandline, is "host is reachable"). When I then call it again, it displays nothing.

What are the issues with the above code? I've difficulty detecting it.

Comment: There is probably an empty line being printed before the output. I think you'll do slightly better if you send all your messages in one thread, read all the output in another thread, and when you're done, parse all of it. If you need interaction, it becomes harder.

Comment: you are exactly right! I was using wireshark to see if the ping happened and missed it actually, thinking the fault lay somewhere else entirely. Thanks.